# Get image from database using codeigniter

Tags: image, codeigniter, blob

I have tried  to set image in database using blob datatype and retrieve from database using codeigniter
this is my viewfile to retrive image from database
**Database**
[image]

**VIEW**

```
<img src="<?php echo site_url("imageUpload/loadImg/")?>/3">
```

**controller**

```
function loadImg($id){
        $this->load->model("imageUploads");
        $rec = $this->imageUploads->getimage($id);
        $ext = $this->imageUploads->getext($id);
        $this->output->set_header('Content-type: image/'.$ext);
        echo $rec;
    }
```

**Model**

```
function getimage($image){
 $query2 = $this->db->query("SELECT images FROM windows_users_image_upload WHERE user_id = $image")->row();
 return $query2->images;
 }
 function getext($id){
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT ext FROM windows_users_image_upload WHERE user_id = $id")->row();
    return $query->ext;
 }
```

But its return me text not image.
Please Help Me to Retrive image from blob datatype
using codeigniter.

Comment: why blob data type to make things difficult?

Comment: @raheelshan i dont know more about blob datatype what i do wrong can you please explain...

Comment: use varchar instead it will solve your problem. bolob data type is not designed for the purpose you are using

Comment: bug i dont have uploaded image in any folder then its work???

Comment: i dont understand what you mean?

Comment: i dont want to store uploaded image in directory. its working. but i want to store uploded image in table. & as you say use varchar insted of blob. if i am use varchar then how my things work.

Answer (score -1):

I used this to retrieve blob image

```
<img src="<?php echo 'data:' . $uploaded->file_type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($uploaded->image_data); ?>" width="200" />
```